# SQL query: selecting only NULL values from a group?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm working with a data table that looks something like this:

```
Names           City            Date        Color    Shape
John Smith      Baltimore       8/1/2015    Blue
John Smith      Baltimore       8/1/2015    Green 
John Smith      Baltimore       8/1/2015             Rectangle
John Smith      Baltimore       8/1/2015
John Smith      Baltimore       8/1/2015             Square
John Smith      Baltimore       8/1/2015
Rob Johnson     Baltimore       8/1/2015
Rob Johnson     Baltimore       8/1/2015
Rob Johnson     Baltimore       8/1/2015
Rob Johnson     Baltimore       8/1/2015
Rob Johnson     Baltimore       8/1/2015
Greg Jackson    Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Greg Jackson    Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Greg Jackson    Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Greg Jackson    Philadelphia    8/1/2015             Circle
Greg Jackson    Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Tom Green       Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Tom Green       Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Tom Green       Philadelphia    8/1/2015    Red
Tom Green       Philadelphia    8/1/2015
Tom Green       Philadelphia    8/1/2015
```

My goal with the query is to SELECT all five of the data types present, but to isolate those values in the Names field that have NULL values in the Color and Shape fields.  I'm writing this SQL in MS Access.  My query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT [Names], [City], [Date], [Color], [Shape]
FROM [databasename]
WHERE 
 (
  ([Color] IS NULL)
   AND
  ([Shape] IS NULL)
 );
```

From the sample data table, I'd like for the results to only include Rob Johnson, since all rows associated with that Name entry have NULL values for the Color and Shape fields.  However, with this query, I'm getting all of the other names as well, with the specific rows with NULL values in the Color and Shape fields being returned.

So, the expected output would look like this:

```
Names           City            Date        Color    Shape
Rob Johnson     Baltimore       8/1/2015
```

I suspect that I need to use a GROUP operator here, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
 SELECT 
    DISTINCT [Names], [City], [Date], [Color], [Shape]
 FROM [table]
 WHERE [Names] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Names] FROM [table] WHERE ([Color] IS NOT NULL) OR 
                                      ([Shape] IS NOT NULL)
 );
```

It can be done in other ways, but this should be close to your original query.

Comment: I think this needs a `distinct` or it will return Rob Johnson 5 times.

Comment: You might want to throw in a `distinct` as the OP only want one row.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mithrandir.  This structure works perfectly for the actual data set.  If I wanted to use a `DISTINCT` operator here, would it be in the `NOT IN (` nest?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the `DISTINCT` in the edited query.  I added that to mine and the results are exactly what I intended.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregate and inner join:

```
SELECT d1.* FROM [database-name] d1
INNER JOIN (
    select Names,MAX(Color) as mc,MAX(Shape) as ms
    from [database-name]
    group by Names
            ) d2
ON d1.Names = d2.Names
WHERE mc IS NULL
AND ms IS NULL
```